# Passing in inline variables to aspx code-behind methods

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to figure out how to call a method with a inline variable, say in the below example, f.

```
<table stuff here>
<% foreach (Foo f in listOfFoos) { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Fubar(f)%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Fubar1(f) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Fubar2(f)%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Fubar3(f)%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Fubar4(f)%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Fubar5(f)%>
    </td>
    <td>

    <asp:Button Text="Click me!" runat="server"  OnClick="FooBar"/>

    </td>
</tr>
```

The definition of the method looks like (defined in the code behind)

```
public void FooBar(Foo myFoo);
```

And I want to call that method on click, and pass in f. 
I'm a newbie to asp.net!

Comment: I'm no expert but the method seems to accept a 'Foo' parameter while you're not sending one in the 'OnClick' event.

Comment: Yup, this is just what I have so far.. I would like to know how to pass parameters into methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First FooBar would have to have this signature:

```
private void FooBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

However, you are better off using [OnCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand.aspx) instead of OnClick, passing the Id of f (or other identifier for f ) as the CommandArgument.

```
<table stuff here>
 <% foreach (Foo f in listOfFoos) { %>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <%= Fubar(f)%>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= Fubar1(f) %>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= Fubar2(f)%>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= Fubar3(f)%>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= Fubar4(f)%>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= Fubar5(f)%>
   </td>
   <td>
     <asp:Button Text="Click me!" runat="server"  OnCommand="FooBar" CommandName="SomeCommnad" CommandArgument="<%= f.Id >" />
   </td>
 </tr>
...
```

The signature of FooBar would be :

```
private void FooBar(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{}
```

Comment: I tried this, but my CommandEventArgs object has the string "<%= f.Id >" as the value and not the id itself

Comment: Try '<%= f.Id >' or '<# f.Id >' . If that doesn't work, I would consider using a repeater like claudio suggested.

Comment: Yeah I tried a lot of it... ended up writing in the whole table in the code behind. SO much more power :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a repeater instead. Adding this from the top of my head so might have some mistakes but the idea of using the repeater is the important part.

**ASPX**

```
<table>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFubars" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Fubar(Container.DataItem as [DATA_ITEM_TYPE!!])%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Fubar1(Container.DataItem as [DATA_ITEM_TYPE!!])%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Fubar2(Container.DataItem as [DATA_ITEM_TYPE!!])%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Fubar3(Container.DataItem as [DATA_ITEM_TYPE!!])%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Fubar4(Container.DataItem as [DATA_ITEM_TYPE!!])%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Fubar5(Container.DataItem as [DATA_ITEM_TYPE!!])%>
            </td>
            <td>

            <asp:Button Text="Click me!" runat="server"  OnClick="FooBar"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
rptFubars.DataSource = listOfFoos;
rptFubars.DataBind();
```